# Parse Cloud Function Response Error

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I wrote this cloud funtion for demo purpose.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {
  res.success("hi");
});
```

But it always returns this error message

```
{
    "code": 141,
    "error": "res.success is not a function"
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting parse server 3.0 there is no response object anymore. Simply return the value and it will work.

```
Parse.Cloud.define(‘hello’, (req) => {
     return ‘ok’;
});
```

For more informations, see the migration guide: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/3.0.0.md

Comment: I did like to ask, what if I actually want to make use of the response on the client side, how can i get that done pls?

Comment: Well, in the example, the client will receive ‘ok’

Comment: thanks for your response, although I am still new to javascript. So, I will like to ask if an object can be returned just the way the 'ok' string was returned.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try before asking?